# React Tabs rendering tab content vertically below one another across Tabs

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render Tabs using react-tabs. The tab contents are rendered one below another (across different tabs) as follows

Adding my code Snippet

```
<Tabs className="tabs">
    <TabList className="tab-header-list">
        <Tab selectedClassName="tab-header-list-items"><b>A</b></Tab>
        <Tab selectedClassName="tab-header-list-items"><b>B</b></Tab>
        <Tab selectedClassName="tab-header-list-items"><b>C</b></Tab>
        <Tab selectedClassName="tab-header-list-items"><b>D</b></Tab>
    </TabList>
    <TabPanel key="1" className="tab-panel">
        <BarChart chartData={userData} />
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel key="3" className="tab-panel">
         <BarChart chartData={userData} />
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel key="2" className="tab-panel">
         <BarChart chartData={userData} />
    </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

CSS used

```
.tabs {
    
}

.tab-header-list{
    color: grey;
}

.tab-header-list-items {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 25%;
    color: black;
}

.tab-panel {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[Actual Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krZoU.png)
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjmDW.png)

Tried all values for flex property, display property, but nothing seems to work.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the height property from .tab-panel

Answer (score 0):

This rule is breaking it

```
.tab-panel {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Specifying height and width like that can break libraries. I would apply these rules to the content within the `.tab-panel`, but not the `.tab-panel` itself